# Show that, for every non-empty subset A of [ n ] , there is an intersecting family F of subsets of [ n ] of size $2^{n − 1}$ with A ∈ F .

Tags: combinatorics

Here is what I have understood this question as:

Every subset of [n] is contained in an intersecting family of size 2^n-1

This is my approach:

I took a set, X={1,2,3}

I list down all the subsets of X: {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3
}, {1,2,3}

Now, I take any one from the above, let us take {2,3}, and name it A

To build an Intersecting family containing A, I take any element from A, let us say, 3. I remove 3 from X and list down all the subsets of our new X: {}, {1}, {2}, {1,2}. I further add 3 to each of these sets, so I have now: {3}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}.

The above list forms an intersecting set containing A, and is of size 4(2^3-1).

In the same way, I can repeat the above steps for all subsets of X, and conclude the same solution.

I apologise for a naive question, but I would like to know if I am correct in this approach, and If I am, How should I approach for a mathematical proof?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to this site. Is the following all you require or have I misunderstood your question?

Let $x$ be an element of a set $X$ which has $n$ elements.

The set $X-\{x\}$ has $n-1$ elements and therefore has $2^{n-1}$ subsets. Add $x$ back into each of these subsets to give us the required family.

Comment: Thankyou for your warm welcome. Absolutely, Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your arguing about the set $X$ is correct, albeit somewhat laborious. But $X=\{1,2,3\}$ is just a special case. Now you have to extend your argument to the general setup in the question; then erase the proof concerning $X$.

You are given a nonempty subset $A\subset[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$. Choose a number $a\in A$ and consider the family
$${\cal F}:=\bigl\{X\subset[n]\bigm| a\in X\bigr\}\ .$$

Comment: Thankyou Christian, It solves my problem very efficiently